# is there a Webview for debian to see what software, packages, etc. are installed?

Tags: debian, system-information

I am searching for a webview where I have some overview over my system on my debian server.

Is there something out there?

Comment: why -1? is my question not clear, off topic, or what?
Let me improve it, but tell me how ;)

Comment: You did not explain what you mean by “webview”. You did not specify the requirements like access control, neither which information you'd like to share (etc. is rather fuzzy). Furthermore, it's unclear what you want to do in the first place. Usually a server status is monitored using software like munin or nagios and packages are managed via direct SSH login or systems like puppet or chef. (I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: What is a webview? I know the word in the context of some programming APIs, but I don't see how that meaning could apply here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply build your own webview. First create a list of installed packages and then serve it:

```
while true; do
  { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; dpkg --get-selections |
      awk '{print $1}'; } | nc -l 8080
done
```

The same technique works for others services as well. To serve CPU and IO statistics, use:

```
while true; do
  { echo -e 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'; iostat -x; } |
    nc -l 8080
done
```

Then simply point the browser to port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lynx`. or `elinks`.  for text mode web browsing.